# Loop to generate 'A0' to 'Z9'

Tags: php

In PHP, doing a `for` loop.

Can you loop from `A0` to `Z9`... I know a simple for loop is like

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i += 1) {
// do things
}
```

But how would it be adding in the alphabet?

Comment: There is no definite sequence between `A0` and `Z9`.

Comment: Why did my question get three downvotes? What did I not include or is this just a stupid question? :(

Comment: weka, it really sounds like you don't know how to do nested loops. Or as if you expected to have a variable with the value "A0" and somehow have it incremented until it gets to "Z9". Maybe if you just asked for iterating over the alphabet? Or how to get the a letter from the alphabet by it's number? I guess it would have been better.  PS: I didn't down vote. (I did consider recommending the project euler, in fact I do recommend it). There goes an upvote ;)

Comment: I love how this question was closed... haha.. okay. Too localized. Whatever. :) I still got my answer. hehehehe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`chr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php):

```
for ($letter = ord('a'); $letter <= ord('z'); ++$letter) {
    for ($number = 0; $number <= 9; ++$number) {
        echo chr($letter) . $number;
    }
}
```

Comment: The double loop is not required, PHP understands how to increment things like `A0` very well.

Comment: @Jack what would a good condition for that be? e.g. `for ($i = 'A0'; $i <= 'Z9'; ++$i)` does not produce the desired result.

Comment: @undefined You're right, judged too soon :)

Answer (score 2):

Here goes another way to do it, this one allows you to change the ordering of the letters or add other symbols.

```
$alphabet = str_split('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 1);
for ($index = 0; $index <= 9; $index += 1)
{
    for ($letter = 0; $letter <= count($alphabet) - 1; $letter++)
    {
        // do things
        echo $alphabet[$letter].$index;
    }
}
```

An example of a reason why you may want to change the symbols is that you want the alphabet of another language. Say... Spanish?

```
$alphabet = str_split('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 1);
```

Don't forget your encoding ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could take advantage of the ASCII (97-122)  range () function and chr () function, avoiding to create character arrays, for example:

```
$range = range(97, 122); # A to Z ascii chars

# loop 9 times
for ($i=1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
    printf("=========== loop %s\n", $i);
    foreach($range as $n) {
        print chr($n);
        print "\n";       
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

<del>I think you will need to map the characters into a array, an loop through the array, using **foreach**</del>

by the answers:

```
<?php
    for ($i = "A00"; $i <= "Z99"; $i++){    
        print $i;
        print "<br>";
    }    
?>
```

will print A00 to Z99, that's very nice.

Comment: It prints too many results though :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  for ($i = "A"; $i <= "Z"; $i++) {
       print $i;
   }
```

prints A-Z.

You may have to introduce an inner loop ranging between 0-9, if you really want to do this.

```
 for ($i="A"; $i<"Z"; $i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j <=9; $j++) {
    print $i.$j;

  }

}
```

Comment: Nope. That prints `A` to `Y`.

Answer (score 1):

Combining the answers from undefined and janenz00 you can do this:

```
for ($i = "A"; $i < "Z"; $i++) {
  for($j = 0; $j < 10; $j++) {
     // Do things like echo $i . $j
  }
}
```

Of course this works if you want to loop through `A0` to `A9`, then `B0` to `B9`, all the way up to `Z0` to `Z9`.